# Add more than 1 DataGridCell with style to a row in wpf dgv programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, colors

I have a class `Ro` that has 4 fields (2 names and 2 colors)

```
public class Ro
    {
        public string c1 { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush c1Color { get; set; }
        public string c2 { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush c2Color { get; set; }
    }
```

I have created a `List of Ro objects`

```
List<Ro> data = new List<Ro>();
            data.Add(new Ro()
            {
                c1 = "7B",
                c1Color = Brushes.Green,
                c2 = "",
                c2Color = Brushes.White
            });
            data.Add(new Ro()
            {
                c1 = "Jot",
                c1Color = Brushes.Green,
                c2 = "",
                c2Color = Brushes.Black
            });
            data.Add(new Ro()
            {
                c1 = "Nav",
                c1Color = Brushes.White,
                c2 = "",
                c2Color = Brushes.Orange
            });
```

Now I want to use this List to populate a `wpf DataGridView` assigning the color to each cell depending on current field of object when looping the list

To do so I created a method that will create ControlTemplate for each cell:

```
        public ControlTemplate CellTemplate(string text, SolidColorBrush color)
        {
            ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate();
            template.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, text);
            template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, color);
            template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
            template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
            if (color == Brushes.White)
                template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
            else
                template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White);
            return template;
        }
```

and also I created a dataColumn `c1`

```
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(
    new DataGridTextColumn
    { Header = "c1" });
```

finally in a foreach loop I create the cells with styles

```
foreach (Ro me in data)
{
    DataGridCell cell0 = new DataGridCell { Template = CellTemplate(me.c1,me.c1Color) };
    dataGrid1.Items.Add(cell0);
  }
```

[image]

so far so good, however when I add the second column and try to apply the same idea like

```
 dataGrid1.Columns.Add(
    new DataGridTextColumn
    { Header = "c2" });

foreach (Ro me in data)
{
    DataGridCell cell0 = new DataGridCell { Template =    CellTemplate(me.c1,me.c1Color) };
    dataGrid1.Items.Add(cell0);

   DataGridCell cell1 = new DataGridCell { Template = CellTemplate(me.c2, me.c2Color) };
    dataGrid1.Items.Add(cell1);
}
```

i get excepction:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled on
>   System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          on System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          on System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32
>   index)
>          on System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size
>   arrangeSize) ...

if I have only one column in dgv I get:
[image]

I tried doing following, but got error, I do not know how to insert a particular cell in a particular column in dgv...

```
 foreach (Ro me in data)
            {
                DataGridCell cell0 = new DataGridCell { Template = CellTemplate(me.c1, me.c1Color) };
                DataGridCell cell1 = new DataGridCell { Template = CellTemplate(me.c2, me.c2Color) };
                dataGrid1.Columns.Insert(0, cell0);
                dataGrid1.Columns.Insert(1, cell0);
                //dataGrid1.Items.Add(cell0);
                //dataGrid1.Items.Add(cell1);
            }
```

How can I add cells in a row programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without doing some gymnastics. Add your columns like this:

```
this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(
    new DataGridTextColumn
    { Header = "c1", Binding = new Binding("c1") } );

this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(
    new DataGridTextColumn
    { Header = "c2", Binding = new Binding("c2") });
this.dataGrid.LoadingRow += DataGrid_LoadingRow;

foreach (Ro me in data)
{
    dataGrid.Items.Add(me);
}
```

See how the code bounds the `C1` column to `c1` property of your `Ro`. See how the code also subscribes to the `LoadingRow` event. Here is the handler for the row which calls the `AlterRow` method asynchronously:

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => AlterRow(e)));
}
```

And here is the rest of the code which basically finds the cells in columns 0 and columns 1 for each row and then figures out the background property and sets it.

```
private void AlterRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = GetCell(dataGrid, e.Row, 0);
    if (cell == null) return;

    var item = e.Row.Item as Ro;
    if (item == null) return;

    cell.Background = item.c1Color;

    cell = GetCell(dataGrid, e.Row, 1);
    if (cell == null) return;

    cell.Background = item.c2Color;
}

public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        var v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T ?? GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}


public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid host, DataGridRow row, int columnIndex)
{
    if (row == null) return null;

    var presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    if (presenter == null) return null;

    // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
    var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
    if (cell == null)
    {
        // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
        host.ScrollIntoView(row, host.Columns[columnIndex]);
        cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Some of the code was borrowed form [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28111347/).

Comment: It works very well. Could you please explain more the line
`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => AlterRow(e)));`  ?

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke means  execute the given action in the UI thread at a later point in time, Invoke will block the thread for each row. `DispatcherPriority.Render` means that this action's priority is not super important so if the UI thread has 2 things it needs to do, it will do anything with a higher priority first. For example, painting the background of a cell to green can wait if the UI thread needs to respond to a button click or something else with higher priority.