# How to change background color of ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

I have been trying this code:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

However I find that only the text color does change but the background still stays the same. I find this behaviour does not change when I switch to other trigger type and even when I simply do:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
```

Comment: I think my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317609/add-more-than-1-datagridcell-with-style-to-a-row-in-wpf-dgv-programatically/41318169#41318169) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thank you for your reply. However, I am new to wpf so can you please further explain it to me?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your situation (the background not appearing to change on the ListViewItem) and took a quick look through the visual tree. The ListViewItem does indeed have a background color of red, so some other object must be masking it. I believe the problem here is from overriding the default style and not completely reconstructing it (in the Template property), as this: `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem"><Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" /></Style>` produces a red background cleanly.

Comment: @TiberiumFusion Thank you for your reply and your nice hint. Yeah, it is easy to change the background color of listviewitem in case of no trigger event. Though, what I really want is to override the style of listviewitem in trigger events...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured out the way to work around. Special thanks to @TiberiumFusion for a great hint. Though, this solution is not as nice as I want.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border x:Name="border">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="border" Value="Blue" />
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```